# Are rational functions on the Riemann sphere invariantly characterized? If so, what about general Riemann surfaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Consider the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}} := \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$. One often considers polynomials on the Riemann sphere, i.e. maps

\begin{equation}
P: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}, P(z) = z \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^N a_n z^n 
\end{equation}

and rational functions on the Riemann sphere, which are quotients of polynomials.

On smooth manifolds, as far as I would think, polynomials and rational functions cannot be invariantly characterized. But what about the Riemann sphere or Riemann surfaces in general?

I would think, that rational functions are invariantly characterized on the Riemann sphere, since conformal automorphisms of the Riemann sphere are rational maps (Möbius transformations) by themselves. Hence any Möbius transformation maps a rational function on a rational function. Hence, I would think that in any chart associated with the holomorphic structure rational functions stay rational functions. Is this true, or am I overlooking something?

If above is true, what is the case for general Riemann surfaces?

Thank you!

Comment: rational functions are the same as holomorphic maps from the Riemann sphere to itself; holomorphic maps from a Riemann surface to the Riemann sphere are the meromorphic functions on that surface

Comment: What do you even mean by polynomials and rational functions on a general smooth manifold?

Comment: The concepts of "polynomials" and "rational functions" are defined by the algebraic properties of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. They are not defined by the topological or geometric properties of these spaces or their compactifications. Thus to generalize "polynomials" and "rational functions" to other spaces, you generalize the algebra to other Fields, groups, modules, etc. Generalizing the topology/geometry doesn't have anything to do with the concept.